# C# - Process is not terminating

Tags: c#, process

I am restoring backup in MySql. But the mysql exe is not terminating.
This is my code -

```
public override bool FullRestore(Stream fileStream)
    {
        try
        {
            ProcessStartInfo proc = new ProcessStartInfo();
            string cmd = string.Format("--database {0} --user={1} --password={2}", config.GetDbName(), config.GetUserName(), config.GetPassword());
            proc.FileName = "mysql";
            proc.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            proc.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
            proc.Arguments = cmd;
            proc.UseShellExecute = false;
            proc.CreateNoWindow = true;
            Process p = Process.Start(proc);
            Stream stream = p.StandardInput.BaseStream;
            Stream file = Utility.ZipNEncrypt.Unzip(fileStream, "XXXXXX");
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            for (int count = 0; (count = file.Read(bytes, 0, 1024)) > 0; )
            {
                stream.Write(bytes, 0, count);
            }
            stream.Flush();
            p.WaitForExit();
            file.Close();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            return false;
        }
    }
```

My BackUp method working well, but this method is not working.(They are vary much similar)

Any Suggestions?

Comment: What do you have against `while` loops?

Comment: I am very much comfortable with for.

Comment: Jayanta: Don't add "Closed" tot he title, either accept an answer or hit the Close button.

Answer (score 6):

You need to close the StandardInput stream:

```
stream.Close();
p.WaitForExit();
```

Otherwise, the program won't terminate because it will be expecting more input.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the code sitting? As a guess, I would imagine that the input stream (`fileStream`) doesn't have an EOF (is it perhaps an incoming pipe from another process? or a network stream?) and therefore you are waiting in `Read` at the end of the current data. Try closing the incoming stream?

(it might be *called* `fileStream`, but I'm not making the assumption that it is actually a file / `FileStream`... I've been bitten by such assumptions before ;-p)

You also might want to think about introducing `using` as appropriate (`file`, perhaps).